# How is it possible that this coat-hanger lifts Thor's hammer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world

How is it possible that this coat-hanger lifts Thor's hammer, when it is not worthy of it? I mean in *Avengers: Age Of Ultron*, Captain America says that an elevator can't lift the hammer because it's not worthy of it.

[image: Thor's hammer on a coat hanger]

Comment: Perhaps because the coat-hanger isn't lifting it.. it is just holding it in place, like the ground does. Whereas the elevator is trying to change the position of the hammer?

Comment: You question is inaccurate. Cap thought an elevator couldn't lift the hammer, but Thor never confirmed this.  Also, we have seen a helicarrier and a quinnjet fly around with the hammer on it.

Comment: Deleted quote, too long

Comment: The coat hanger supports the hammer the same way the ground does.  The ground isn't any worthier than the coat hanger.

Comment: You remember it backwards, [Captain America used the elevator as an example for how machines _could_ move the hammer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XrDgwFxRLo),  even though it's a machine and therefore not able to be "worthy".

Answer (score 8):

Thor (or possibly another worthy wielder) has the power to place his hammer wherever he wants.  He can set it down on a table (even though that makes the table "hold" it up); he can hang it from a peg.  What is forbidden is for an living/animate creature/entity to pick it up (and thus wield it).

Comment: +1 He can even set it on top of a person to hold them in place.